# MySQL: Creating a table from another table with a lock

Tags: mysql, sql, locking

I have a rather large table with 36m rows. I want to create another table that contains one of the columns in random order.

```
CREATE TABLE random_stamps AS SELECT time FROM cur_a order by rand();
```

The problem is that I am exceeding the lock table size as expected. I tried locking the table `cur_a` but while `cur_a` is locked I cannot create another table.

I can't increase the size of the lock table because I don't have root access to the server.

Comment: rows in database tables are *unordered* by default, it you think that insertion order determines output order of `SELECT` - you're wrong

Comment: You are creating with just one field, maybe you need a View?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing what you want by adding another column:

```
CREATE TABLE random_stamps AS
    SELECT time, rand() as rand
    FROM cur_a;

CREATE INDEX idx_random_stamps_rand ON random_stamps(rand, time);
```

Then, when you fetch the data, you can use `order by`, which will use the index:

```
SELECT rs.*
FROM random_stamps rs
ORDER BY rand;
```

Comment: That query still exceeds the size of the lock size table.

Comment: @user3446746 . . . You might find this interesting:  https://major.io/2010/01/29/mysql-the-total-number-of-locks-exceeds-the-lock-table-size/.